# Kafka Consumer Offset Lag Causes Kafka Down

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I've realized that one of my topics left messages inside of consumer offset and I'm trying to track it down in KafkaDrop but I've seen that for 3 of my __consumer_offsets partition has high last offset value. I have also checked messages but some of them belongs to Sept which is 3 months ago. How can I get rid of these messages without giving harm to whole kafka?

Answer (score 0):

Data in the offsets topic is automatically removed overtime, and high offset simply means that you have many consumers for your cluster, nothing more, and doesn't affect performance at all. You shouldn't manually remove data from it.

Comment: But it causes kafka to be down and these messages are not consumed by consumer. They were there like 3 months. kafka version is 0.11 btw

Comment: No, a large offset topic is not what causes Kafka to be down. If it fills up the mounted volumes, then **that does**. But I've seen the offsets topic be several TB large in our production clusters, and it's running fine. Not really clear how you're checking timestamps of groups